# Questions about codes in the setter of a DependencyProperty in a user control

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, winrt-xaml, dependency-properties

I am making a display of time/clock as a user control (`ClockControl`) on a page, the actual time model is driven from a `DateTime` object from another class (`ClockTime`). I have 2 textblocks on the `ClockControl`:

1. Textblock 'Second_update_by_binding' is bound to a dependency property 'Second_binded' which in turn is bound to model ClockTime 'Second'.
2. Textblock 'Second_update_by_manipulating' is updated by manipulating the value of the model ClockTime 'Second' so that it adds '0' at front if the 'Second' is only 1 digit (or less than 10)

I managed to achieve what I want regardless if its the best approach. However, I have come across a few questions that I don't quite understand why they happen. In particular, its the logic behind the code inside the getter/setter within the dependency property in the Clock user control that I am most confused of.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="App1.MainPage" ...">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <local:ClockControl x:Name="useControl" 
               Second_binded="{Binding Second}" 
               Second_manipulated="{Binding Second}"  />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ClockTime clock;
    DispatcherTimer Timer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        clock = new ClockTime();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = clock;
          // I am adding this DispatchTimer to force the update of the text 
          // 'Second_update_by_manipulating' on the ClockControl since the
          // Binding of Second_manipulated doesnt work
        Timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1) };
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        useControl.Second_manipulated = clock.Second.ToString();
    }
}
```

ClockTime model:

```
class ClockTime : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ClockTime()
    {
        var Timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1) };
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        Second = DateTime.Now.Second;
    }

    //===================================================
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    //===================================================
    private int _second;
    public int Second
    {
        get { return this._second; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._second)
            {
                this._second = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Second");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ClockControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="App1.ClockControl" ...>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Second_update_by_manipulating"  />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Second_update_by_binding" Text="{Binding Second_binded}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ClockControl.cs:

```
public sealed partial class ClockControl : UserControl
{
    public ClockControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }
    //==================================
    public String Second_binded
    {
        get {
            return (String)GetValue(Second_bindedProperty); 
        }
        set {
            Debug.WriteLine(" in Second_binded ");
            SetValue(Second_bindedProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Second_bindedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Second_binded", 
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ClockControl), 
        new PropertyMetadata(""));
    //==================================
    public String Second_manipulated
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)GetValue(Second_manipulatedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            Second_update_by_manipulating.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(value)<10) ? "0"+value : value;
            Debug.WriteLine(" in Second_manipulated ");
            SetValue(Second_manipulatedProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Second_manipulatedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Second_manipulated",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ClockControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(""));
    //==================================
}
```

so here are my questions:

1. Why the debugging code **Debug.WriteLine(" in Second_binded ");** within the setter of Second_binded dependency property in ClockControl is never called when the 'Second' in model ClockTime is being updated.
2. The code **Debug.WriteLine(" in Second_manipulated ");** within the setter of Second_manipulated dependency property in ClockControl is called and the code **Value_1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(value)<10) ? "0"+value : value;** is executed to change the text on the ClockControl, but it only works after adding another DispatchTimer withtin the MainPage.cs to force the code **useControl.Second_manipulated = clock.Second.ToString();** to update the time. Why I have to do it this way to update Second_manipulated, even though I have already set Second_manipulated binded to Second in the MainPage.xaml?

Any ideas and comments to enlighten my knowledge on C# is very welcomed.

thanks

Ken

Comment: @marc_s, thank you for updating my texts :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track changes in a `DependencyProperty`, you have to register a [PropertyChangedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) handler. The property setter is not triggered by the system when the value of a binding is updated.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Second_bindedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Second_binded",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ClockControl),
        new PropertyMetadata("", PropertyChangedCallback));

private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
             DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(" in Second_binded callback");
}
```

The reason why your setter is hit in the second property is because you force it yourself with `useControl.Second_manipulated = clock.Second.ToString();`, which is not the correct way of using bindings.

Comment: Thanks about the callBack method, that is useful! so it doesnt matter what you put in the setter & the getter for binding?

Comment: Not for binding no, only when it gets called from code.